# Orbits, stabilizers, and fixed points

Tags: abstract-algebra

Question : Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and let $H$ act on $G/H$ by translation. Find the orbits, stabilizers, and fixed points of the action.

I think stabilizer is g$H$g^-1
...but I don't know orbit and fixed points..

Comment: ...please...? And what have you done so far?!

Comment: I don't want to. (It's not polite to phrase your questions in the form of commands.)

Comment: sorry..I don't Know how can I approach this..please help me

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

The action is

$$\forall\,x,g\in G\;,\;\;x\cdot(gH):=(xg)H$$

letting $\,X\,$ be *the set* of all left cosets, thus:

$$\mathcal Orb(xH):=\{\,gxH\;;\;g\in G\,\}=X$$

Can you see why is there *only* one orbit (i.e., the action is transitive)?

$$Stab(xH):=\{\,g\in G\;;\;gxH=xH\iff x^{-1}gx\in H\,\}$$

Can you show, for example, that $\;Stab(H)=H\;$ ?

Fixed points:

$$xH\in X^G:=\{\,x\in X\;;\;gx=x\,\,\,\forall\,g\in G\}\iff \forall\,g\in G\;,\;\;gxH=xH\ldots$$